# PHP Error "Unknown: failed to open stream... in Unknown on line 0..." when editing php files

Tags: php, lighttpd, fpm

I get a strange php error:

```
2022-03-14 10:52:19: (mod_fastcgi.c.421) FastCGI-stderr: PHP message: 
PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: 
No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required 
'var/www/vhosts/webdev/sites/test/hello.php'
(include_path='.') in Unknown on line 0
```

**Long explanation:**

1. I create a file hello.php in my webroot, having the content:

   `<?php echo("hello"); ?>`
2. I run this file in a browser, all is fine, it shows "hello"
3. Now I *edit* this file so the content now is:

   `<?php echo("hello"); echo("world"); ?>`
4. I run this edited file in a browser => The error is shown
5. I reload the page (F5 or ctrl-R) => all is working fine now

**In other words:**
Whenever I **edit** a php file and try to run it in a browser, I get this error message. After reloading the page it works!

*That is the real strange thing, after reloading everything is working fine!!!*

**My config**

- a local raspberry pi running raspbian
- webserver: lighttpd (standard install from repo)
- php7.3-fpm (standard install from repo)
- all file permissions in my web dev folder are 775, all files are www-data:www-data owned
- NO selinux running (like in other answers suggested)
- the php.ini is pretty much untouched, some options:

  ```
  auto_prepend_file = 
   auto_append_file = 
   include_path = "."
  ```
- there are no other hidden config files in the folder

With html files there are no problems. So it must be a php-fpm problem.
I am out of ideas now. It might be a very easy fix, but I am not a Pro.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: How are you creating the file, and how are you editing it? Are you using the same program/command for both?

Comment: @aynber Files are created and edited using notepad++ on Windows. Encoding of files is UTF-8 and line endings are unix-style (LF)

Comment: Sounds weird. I have 2 questions that might or might not help you. 

**1.** If you wait a few minutes without reloading do you still experience the error? Can it be that notepad++ takes time to save the file remotely?

**2.** Another weird thing I see in the message: 'var/www/vhosts/webdev/sites/test/hello.php' is missing the initial "/"? How is your webroot defined in lighthttp in the fcgi wrapper?

Comment: @AndreaOlivato SOLVED. There was a missing leading "/" in my webroot string. Knew it was a stupid mistake. In my defense: there is a wordpress test installation running in another vhost that shows no errors. Thank you so so so much for helping me!! Post this as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @ArchyDraeyfus sure, done! Add as a comment to the answer which exact configuration you've changed to help other people who might encounter the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the error log, the path doesn't start with a slash "/"

`var/www/vhosts/webdev/sites/test/hello.php`

which indicates a misconfiguration in lighttpd/fastcgi configuration

Fixing the path should make everything work correctly.

Comment: In my lighttpd vhost config file I had: `server.document-root = "var/www/vhosts/webdev"`. I added a leading slash to the path to make it absolute, like Andrea suggested, and now it works.

Comment: To summarise again: This was NOT a PHP problem, it was because of a wrong web server configuration.